# Why can't ValGrind find my symbols?

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind

I don't know what I've done wrong, but I can't seem to fix this.

According to `file`,

```
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, BuildID[sha1]=0x436d17ab04dc54f35f1a8e6a16d4f87aaf79a0e9, not stripped
```

It clearly says "not stripped". And yet, when I run ValGrind,

```
--27709-- Reading syms from /root/ValGrind/test (0x8048000)
--27709--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
```

I can't figure out *why* the object doesn't have a symbol table... What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Is it because the binary is 32-bit, and I'm running a 64-bit OS? Or should that not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executable is statically linked; maybe that causes the problem?

Actually, what *is* the problem you're after? Because the "object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table" message is just debug output from Valgrind, so it shouldn't matter much.

Btw. according to http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.hiddenbug Valgrind doesn't work well with statically-linked applications anyway.

Comment: The binary _is_ statically-linked. I guess that's my problem?

Comment: Well static linking will at least give you incomplete results when running Valgrind, so yeah, that is _a_ problem. According to doc you can use the option "--soname-synonyms=somalloc=NONE" as workaround (I didn't try it that actually works, though).

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add the `-g` or `-ggdb` flag when compiling/linking?

Comment: Nope, I definitely did that. (And the binary got larger.)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the binary from static linking to dynamic. Installed 32-bit libraries. Works now.

(PS. To anybody else desperately struggling with OpenSUSE's awful package search, the correct package name is `libstdc++6-32bit`.)